# nodemon app crashed waiting for file changes before starting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nodemon

$ npm start

> server@1.0.0 start
> nodemon index.js

[nodemon] 2.0.19
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,JSON
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
D:\React\authInMern\server\index.js:8
connection();
^

TypeError: connection is not a function
at Object. (D:\React\authInMern\server\index.js:8:1)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:inter`enter code here`nal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

index.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const { connection } = require("./db");

// database connection
connection();

// Middlewares
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors());

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;`enter code here`
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port $(port)...`));
```

```
db.js

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

module.exports = () => {
    const connectionParams = {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    };
    try {
       mongoose.connect(process.env.DB, connectionParams);
       console.log("Connected to database successfully")
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log("could not connect to database");
        
    }
};
```

```
$ npm start

> server@1.0.0 start
> nodemon index.js

[nodemon] 2.0.19
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv'
Require stack:
- D:\React\git\AuthInMern\server\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\React\git\AuthInMern\server\index.js:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'D:\\React\\git\\AuthInMern\\server\\index.js' ]
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Please share the code on index.js

Comment: The error says that `connection();` (line 8 on `index.js`) is not valid since `connection` is not a function. Please share its definition on `db.js`.

Comment: It should be `const connection = require('./db')`.

Comment: D:\React\authInMern\server\node_modules\mongodb-connection-string-url\lib\index.js:86
            throw new MongoParseError('Invalid scheme, expected connection string to start with "mongodb://" or "mongodb+srv://"');

Comment: If that is the next error you have to show us how `process.env.DB` looks like. When doing so please **do not** add the actual password.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the error is changing once its fixed

Comment: @sujithKumar What is the current error you are having? I  suggest you make that a new questions as the original question was answered and things are getting clustered in here.

Comment: @Palladium02 Some files are missing in my source code. I am the Beginner to nodejs so I get confused and stuck. Thank u for your support

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way, if you want the connection function to be destructured

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const connection = () => {
    const connectionParams = {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    };
    try {
       mongoose.connect(process.env.DB, connectionParams);
       console.log("Connected to database successfully")
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log("could not connect to database");
        
    }
};

module.exports = { connection }
```